# How to add a github library dependency with ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I created an asp.net core project using just the command line program `dotnet`.

Is it possible to add dependencies for libraries found on github without downloading it manually and adding the library to the /bin folder?

I know there is a dotnet restore command, but not sure if that would be to pull down dependencies that I add to my project.

Is there a specific file to add dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add dependency libraries ("packages") directly from GitHub, they should be published on NuGet (most of them are there) or similar.

Usually, library authors put link to NuGet directly in their project description page ion GitHub.

When you known package name on NuGet, you can run this:

```
dotnet add package <packagename>
```

And package will be added to your project (open `projectname.csproj` file in notepad - you will see all packages there).

Now you should run `dotnet restore` to actually download package to your machine.

More details about `dotnet` command [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/)